# How to check to see if reactiveValues instance is empty or has a value R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to create different ggplots from user input, based on whether the user wants facets and/or a variable to be colored.  I need to check to see the varSelectInput user input is empty or not to do this, though.  My code is below, starting with getting the user input, then getting the indices of the columns to pass into ggplot2, and finally checking to see which of the four inputs (x axis, y axis, facet column, and color column) the user wants to use.  The user needs to click a "Plot" button to make the graph.

```
    output$descrxaxis_Variable <- renderUI({
      varSelectInput(inputId = "descrxaxis", label = "Choose x axis variable", data = descrDataMelted_selVars$df)})
    
    output$descryaxis_Variable <- renderUI({
      varSelectInput(inputId = "descryaxis", label = "Choose y axis variable", data = descrDataMelted_selVars$df,
                     multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE)})
    
    output$descrFacet_Variable <- renderUI({
      varSelectInput(inputId = "descrfacet", label = "Choose facet variable", data = descrDataMelted_selVars$df,
                     multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE)})
    
    output$descrColor_Variable <- renderUI({
      varSelectInput(inputId = "descrcolor", label = "Choose color variable", data = descrDataMelted_selVars$df,
                     multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE)})
    
    x_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
    observeEvent(input$descrxaxis, {
      x_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df) == input$descrxaxis)})
    
    y_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
    observeEvent(input$descryaxis, {
      y_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df) == input$descryaxis)})
    
    facet_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
    observeEvent(input$descrfacet, {
      facet_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df) == input$descrfacet)})

    color_ind <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
    observeEvent(input$descrcolor, {
      color_ind$val <- which(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df) == input$descrcolor)})
    
    observeEvent(input$descrBtnPlot,{
      if (!is.null(x_ind) & !is.null(y_ind) & is.null(facet_ind) & is.null(color_ind)){
        req(x_ind$val)
        req(y_ind$val)
        p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars$df, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[y_ind$val])) + geom_point()}
      
      if (!is.null(x_ind) & !is.null(y_ind) & is.null(facet_ind) & !is.null(color_ind)){
        req(x_ind$val)
        req(y_ind$val)
        p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars$df, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[y_ind$val],
                                                           color = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[color_ind$val])) + geom_point()}
      
      if (!is.null(x_ind) & !is.null(y_ind) & !is.null(facet_ind) & is.null(color_ind)){
        req(x_ind$val)
        req(y_ind$val)
        p <- ggplot(descrDataMelted_selVars$df, aes_string(x = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[x_ind$val], y = colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[y_ind$val])) + geom_point() +
          facet_wrap(eval(expr(~!!ensym(colnames(descrDataMelted_selVars$df)[facet_ind$val]))))
      
        output$descrSummaryStatsPlot <- renderPlotly(ggplotly(p))}
    })
```

What do I have to change to be able to tell if facet_ind and/or color_ind are empty?  I've tried a bunch of different ways, but nothing has worked.  Thank you.

Comment: Please post a minimally reproducible example with some sample data.

Comment: I got it to work using selectInput, but I feel like it's a hack.  Like the saying goes, "there has to be a better way!".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RStudio, there's a really neat debugging tool you can use for Shiny if you call `browser()`.

If you're just trying to check what the values of `facet_ind` and `color_ind`, then place `browser()` right before that line of code, and then run your app. When you execute your app, you should enter the debugging tool in RStudio, and you should be able to execute code line-by-line and there should be a panel in RStudio where you can see what the values of your variables are after each line of code.

See here for more details: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, specifically not wanting something to render until there were `reactiveValues`. Upon initialization `reactiveValues` is empty but it is still Truthy. So I did:

```
req(length(reactiveValuesToList(v)) !=0)
```

Here is a full example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("click", "Click"),
  textOutput("value")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  v <- reactiveValues()
  
  observeEvent(input$click, {
    v$x <- 100
  })
  
  output$value <- renderPrint({
    req(length(reactiveValuesToList(v)) !=0)
    
    print(length(reactiveValuesToList(v)))
    print(v$x)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]